# Moving each blog date to bottom of excerpt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

On the site homepage, there is a grid section with the two latest blog posts. I need Javascript that will move the date to the bottom of each block (outside of the border). The link is: http://abundancepractice-building.flywheelsites.com

Here is the structure:

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4">
  <div class="et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper">
    <div class="et_pb_blog_grid clearfix et_pb_bg_layout_light blog-section" style="position: relative; height: 400px;">

    <article id="post-226" class="et_pb_post et_pb_no_thumb post-226 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">


      <h2><a href="http://abundancepractice-building.flywheelsites.com/what-you-learned-in-grad-school-is-ruining-your-website-and-10-ways-to-fix-it/">What You Learned In Grad School is Ruining Your Website (and 10 ways to fix it)</a></h2>

        <p class="post-meta">  Jun 5, 2015  </p>Blog excerpt text...        
    </article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->
```

So the p.post-meta needs to be attached to the bottom of the block for each. I'm not a Javascript expert, but here's what I tried so far:

```
jQuery(function($){
$( ".post-meta:nth-child(1)" ).appendTo(".et_pb_post.et_pb_no_thumb:nth-    child(1)");
$( ".post-meta:nth-child(2)" ).appendTo(".et_pb_post.et_pb_no_thumb:nth-child(2)");
});
```

and

```
jQuery(function($){

if ($('body').hasClass('et_pb_blog_grid')) {
$('.et_pb_post p')
.each(function() {
  var n = jQuery(this).find(".post-meta").html();
  $(n).clone().insertAfter(jQuery(this).find('.et_pb_post.et_pb_no_thumb'));
});
}

});
```

Comment: Just reorder in the PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use javascript to do this.

Just edit the template and move

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

to before the post date.

Edit:

open your homepage in the wp admin area and make a note of the template name it uses.

Then search your template files in your themes folder for that name it should appear like:

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Homepage
 */
?>
```

That will be the file you need to modify

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm confused how to move it exactly though. The only places I found 'the_excerpt' was in functions.php and custom_functions.php. In functions.php:
`if ( 'on' === $show_content ) {  
   global $more;
    $more = null;
    the_content( __( 'read more...', 'Divi' ) );
 } else {
 if ( has_excerpt() ) {
  the_excerpt();
  } else {
  truncate_post( 270 );
  }`

In custom_functions.php:

`add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');` and
`$post_excerpt = '';
  $post_excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );`

I'm just not sure how/where to rearrange to?

Comment: Okay, I've found the correct file and moving it worked.. but here's my issue now: I have a child theme and don't want to change anything in my parent functions.php file. I've been trying to copy and paste the specific section where the title is into the child functions.php and edit there, but it causes a blank screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.